# update cart after added a new record - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the my main page, I have a list of records. this list loaded at the first time(from database). there is a button on main page that it opens a new popup window and user can add a new record to database . now, I would like to reload my list when user click on `add new record` on popup page.

my main page:

```
<div id="mydiv">

//my list

</div>
```

open popup on main page:

```
 <li><a  href="#product-quick-view-add-to-cart" onClick="quickView({{$o->id}});">add to cart<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
```

---

```
   function quickView(id){

        $('#product-quick-view-add-to-cart').html("waiting...");
        $.post("{{base_url()}}cart/getPopUpContent", {id:id} , function(data){
            $('#product-quick-view-add-to-cart').html(data); //opened popup
        });
        }

//the `data` content on callback from ajax is a popup content that it has a button as `add new record`.
```

Now,How can reload `mydiv`  from server after click on `add new record` on popup page ?

Comment: You could just do another ajax call to get the data? Or if you already have all the data you need you can just append it to the cart?

Comment: if I can call an ajax method, I'll get all data from database and load them on my list.

Comment: Sorry I don't really know what you are asking... just call your ajax function then when they click on the button? You didn't show us any of your dialog script.